# Does HTML data attribute, or similar, exists in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to get some additional data from components and I don't know how. If it's possible, how can I get that and set it to a state?

Comment: Can you please specify more about your question? May be with an example

Comment: React Native utilizes [props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props). Could it be that it is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props). The example from that documentation page is the `Image` component, which takes a `source` prop:

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> import { AppRegistry, Image } from 'react-native';
>
> export default class Bananas extends Component {
>   render() {
>     let pic = {
>       uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
>     };
>     return (
>       <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> // skip this line if using Create React Native App
> AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Bananas);
> ```

Your component receives props as the first argument to its constructor (if it's a `class`) or function (if it's a stateless functional component).

> If it's possible, how can I get that and set it to a state?

You wouldn't usually do that. You might set state based on props (for instance: if you had a counter, you might have a prop for what number to start with and a state item for the current number), but usually you don't copy props to state directly. You can use props when rendering.